# Android, icon been duplicate when i install my app on the device

Tags: android

I try to install the app that i develop on my device  (Htc desire) and i see that the icon of the app is duplicate

what i need to change to don't late that happen?

how could i delete one of the icon?

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 16):

I came up this issue today, I am using Gradle.

I found out there was a folder `./build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` was generated from gradle build, and it had duplicate intent-filter of category launcher.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

One of it was came by gradle dependencies compile project. So I went back and check dependencies project and remove it, and the problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Android's Launcher app creates an icon for each Activity in your Application that includes the intent filter `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Remove this intent filter from all Activities that should not be launched. In other words, define this `intent filter` in your main Activity, and in your main Activity only.

Answer (score 1):

for change icon of app..

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

see this line in your menifest file.. and change "@drawable/your_icon_name" instead of "@drawable/icon"

Answer (score 0):

do you use the default icone of android , or u have change the app's icon from the manifest ?

if that's right , try using the default icon of android , and then see if that will duplicate the app's icon or not

Answer (score 0):

try to use this ,

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.(your action )" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

and you have to use ur main activity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

let me comments if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

force stop your launcher from settings - app manager and clear cash data of launcher and check your problem is resolved

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?