# Too many aps when i test my android app on my phone

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio, and I'm using my phone to test my app.
When I run it, it displays too many apps of the same app. I have 10 Java classes (activities) and one app appears for each activity on the phone. Why?

Comment: Please spell-check title: `Apps` and *I*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, icon been duplicate when i install my app on the device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028695/android-icon-been-duplicate-when-i-install-my-app-on-the-device)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure on your manifest you don't have the

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

per activity... only your main activity should have that.

Comment: I figured it out by myself, but thanks anyway :) @Raykud