# two app icons are showing android. Is there any fault in my mainfest?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-manifest, appicon

In my manifest few intent-filter used but i removed all intent filter except laucher but still two icons. Is there any other reason for two icons?

I am editing this post and also adding my app build.gradle as well project build.gradle

This my manifest

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"          
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.user.LoginUserActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />

    </application>
```

Comment: I solved this issue from   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028695/android-icon-been-duplicate-when-i-install-my-app-on-the-device        I went to this path   /build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml  and found that there is two Lancher.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem from this link

[Android, icon been duplicate when i install my app on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028695/android-icon-been-duplicate-when-i-install-my-app-on-the-device)

I went to this path /build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml and found that there is two LAUNCHER.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest you are using two icons like icon and roundIcon.Hence you are getting two icons maybe.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" //app icon
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon" ---> //another app icon
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
```

try to remove any one.

Comment: @ g.brahma    by removing one icon giving same result.

Comment: @UnityTaru can you also try to remove this line in manifest "tools: replace=" android: icon"? I don't know why its used there.

Comment: @ g.brahma    "tools: replace=" android: icon"    This tells the merger to use my manifest icon and not of other libraries.

Comment: are you create shortcut icons pragmatically ??

Comment: @dastan  not creating shortcut icons

Comment: I solved this issue from stackoverflow.com/questions/6028695/… I went to this path /build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml and found that there is two Lancher.

Answer (score 0):

**1) If icon problem**

**Possibility 1**

Check your all drawable(mdpi,xdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi etc...) folders that icon is same or not with same name

**Possibility 2**

If you use any libraries or module, change name of that icon from app_name to any other.

**2) if launcher problem**

If it is launcher problem so uninstall all application from your device. Make sure only one launcher activity in your Manifest and run again.

Comment: @ Shel S9  everything was fine as u mentioned above.

Comment: I solved this issue from stackoverflow.com/questions/6028695/… I went to this path /build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml and found that there is two Lancher.

Answer (score 0):

You are having two icons mentioned in the application manifest, see this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
```

Try to remove the `roundIcon`. Hope this will work. If it doesn't works, also replqce the `tools:replace="android:icon"` with this: `tools:replace="icon"`

But don't forget to declare your manifest header like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Comment: i tried both the process u said but the result is same

Comment: I solved this issue from stackoverflow.com/questions/6028695/… I went to this path /build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml and found that there is two Lancher.

Comment: But you have to accept one of the answers to your question. Check out the answer that helped you the most, and accept it. You can also add your own answer so that others get help.